# About regular expression in node.js

Tags: node.js, regex

I have a string, and I try to determine if some characters are included, for example

const array = ["dso","sboy","sex","mos","jkl"] //there're lot of words

And also I want to determine if the string contains urls, how can I write this in `node.js`? Thanks.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to write a regular expression yourself yet?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I can write with one word or the url, but I don't know how use `array`

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, my mind fell into the array, I can use

```
let reg = /(?!.*dso|.*sboy|.*sex|.*mos|.*jkl)^.*$/
```